# Firebase server authentication app secret

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Seems like the easiest way to grant write access through REST to firebase is to include "auth =database_secret" to the end of the post request I'm making.

This is a 'legacy' authentication - is there any reason why I shouldn't use this method?

Is it safe to just send the request with the database secret in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database secret is not terribly secure, nor is it very flexible.  You can think of it like a password.  Anyone who has your password has full access to your database.  If you accidentally give up that password (or ship it in a piece of software that ends up on a computer that you don't fully control), now you have a problem, because you will have to figure out how to reset that password to reject access to the people who have it.  This has the side effect of also rejecting access to all the people who use the password legitimately.  Sounds like kind of a hassle, right?

A better way to manage access is through OAuth.  You can selectively choose which accounts (both personal accounts and service accounts) should have access to your data.  You can choose, at any time, to allow or reject access to any one of these accounts, without affecting the other accounts.  There is no "password" to share or manage.  It's just more secure and flexible.